# Invalid or unexpected token in my Vuejs javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In my vue component js code, I received this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

**This is my code:**

```
Vue.component('pickpoint-info', {

    template : '<table>\ // in this line I get the error
                    <tbody>\
                        <tr v-for="item in items" v-on:click="selectPickPoint(this)">\
                            <td width="50" align="center"><input name="pickpointid" type="radio" value="{{ item.customer_id }}"></td>\
                            <td width="300">\
                                <b>{{ item.name }}</b> <i style="font-size:9px;">#{{ item.customer_id }}</i>\
                                <br>\
                                {{ item.address }}\ 
                                <br>\ 
                                {{ item.postal_code }}\
                                <a href="{{ item.map_link }}" target="_blank" style="font-size:10px;">(ver en el mapa</a>)\
                            </td>\
                        </tr>\
                    </tbody>\
                </table>\
    ',
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to write backticks `, not simple quotes '

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using a string as your template, instead use the `HTML 5` template tag and reference it:

```
<template id="my-template">
  <table> in this line I get the error
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items" v-on:click="selectPickPoint(this)">
        <td width="50" align="center">
          <input name="pickpointid" type="radio" value="{{ item.customer_id }}">
        </td>
        <td width="300">
          <b>{{ item.name }}</b> <i style="font-size:9px;">#{{ item.customer_id }}</i>
          <br> {{ item.address }}
          <br> {{ item.postal_code }}
          <a href="{{ item.map_link }}" target="_blank" style="font-size:10px;">(ver en el mapa</a>)
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Then you can reference it by `id`:

```
Vue.component('pickpoint-info', {
  template: "#my-template"
});
```

If you want to use a string then check the ends of your lines and make sure there is no whitespace after the backslash, I think your error lies on these two lines:

```
{{ item.address }}\ 
  <br>\
```

Both have `whitespace` at the end that you need to remove.

Comment: Or if he want to go with strings, there are dedicated template strings as part of ES2015.But I agree with you - about using HTML5 `template` tags.

Comment: Yes, although they would need to be compiled and even `babel` doesn't include the `template literals` transform by default, so if you're doing that you might as well use a single page component, which is much cleaner.

Comment: Mmm but this is a component, I don´t use html in this view. In anywhere html file I want use the tags <pickpoint-info></pickpoint-info> and renderized the component.

Comment: You can just seperate them out into a views file and include them in your HTML. The problem with using strings as complex templates is exactly what you are experiencing, trying to find where you have missed a concatenation or escape character. You should also look at [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) they make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you where I think the problem with your string template is.

Answer (score 0):

For writing backtick, you can check this link [examples on different keyboards](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows)

In my case (Using qwertz keyboard) it is "Alt Gr" + "7" (maybe you need to press it twice).